# Use C definitions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, ios

**I would define some helper functions, and i prefer write them in C instead of objective-C.**

Which is the "best practice" to add header and implementation C file in a Objective C project ?

If i need to use Objective-c definition in my functions, what i need to include in my header C file (UIKit?) ?

Example: i'd like to create a shortcut to NSLog for NSString , can i create in my C file something similar to this code ? :

```
void MYLog (NSString *string){
  NSLog(@"%@",string);
}
```

Comment: Why create a shortcut for `NSLog()` to take a single `NSString` when it already take a string, and **optionaly** more parameters?

Comment: Every time I've thought *I'll just create a C API here*, I've regretted it... An Objective-C version isn't that much more work, rarely incurs a significant amount of overhead vs. straight C and is considerably more versatile.

Comment: ehm... Peylow you are right is completely useless ...let's say this is an example to help me formulate the question :P -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure you can use objective-c functions in your c code (and vice versa) if your source file is compiled as c/obj-c code (has .m extension or type set manually in xcode)

To make core functions work I think importing `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` and `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` should be sufficient. These headers may be already imported in your precompiled header (*.pch file) so you may not even need to import them.

If you want to extend some UIKit classes functionality consider also implementing custom class category instead of using plain c functions.

Comment: And put your C code in a .m file so things like `@"foo"` are understood by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily. You shouldn’t have to import anything, as you have `UIKit` and `Foundation` already imported by the prefix header. The logger function would look like this:

```
// Logger.h
void MyLog(NSString *str);

// Logger.m
#import "Logger.h"
void MyLog(NSString *str) {…}
```

Comment: Thank you zoul, in your opinion, can i work with .c extension or i need to use .m ?

Comment: You should use `.m`, so that the compiler understands Objective-C in those files.